# Bootstrap 3 Form Responsiveness

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

The following fiddle shows a sample form that has 3 "columns", each column has a label and an input.
   http://jsfiddle.net/Hidalgo/GXT66/1/

```
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="txtField1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Caption 1:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" id="txtField1" name="txtField1" class="form-control" />
   </div>
```

When the screen is being reduced, all columns collapse into a vertical form (caption on top and input at the bottom).
How can I (if possible) make the form response is such way that when the screen is reduced but not to a smart phone size, only the 3rd column is collapsed. So essentially the form would have 2 columns instead of 3. And then, further, when the screen is reduced to the smart phone size, all columns are collapsed to a vertical form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col-sm-3` and `col-md-2`...

http://www.bootply.com/116952